# ReorderableListView inside SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I try to use `ReorderableListView` inside `SingleChildScrollView`, but I receive a error:

```
I/flutter ( 9049): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9049): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 9049): BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
I/flutter ( 9049): These invalid constraints were provided to _RenderLayoutBuilder's layout() function by the following
I/flutter ( 9049): function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
I/flutter ( 9049):   RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter ( 9049): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter ( 9049):   BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 9049): User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 9049):   ReorderableListView file:///Users/vvv/Documents/Projects/WorkoutBook/lib/main.dart:43:12
I/flutter ( 9049): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 9049): #0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>.throwError (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:501:9)
I/flutter ( 9049): #1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:548:21)
I/flutter ( 9049): #2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:552:6)
I/flutter ( 9049): #3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1618:24)
I/flutter ( 9049): #4      RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter ( 9049): #5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #8      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:744:15)
I/flutter ( 9049): #9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #10     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:497:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #17     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #30     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter ( 9049): #31     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:444:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #32     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #33     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter ( 9049): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #38     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1232:11)
I/flutter ( 9049): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #40     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #44     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #55     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3140:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #57     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter ( 9049): #58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #71     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:152:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #72     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1578:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #73     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
I/flutter ( 9049): #74     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:341:19)
I/flutter ( 9049): #75     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:761:13)
I/flutter ( 9049): #76     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:280:5)
I/flutter ( 9049): #77     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
I/flutter ( 9049): #78     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:975:9)
I/flutter ( 9049): #79     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:784:7)
I/flutter ( 9049): #88     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter ( 9049): #89     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter ( 9049): #90     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
I/flutter ( 9049): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 9049): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderStack#68003 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter ( 9049):   creator: Stack ← _Theatre ← Overlay-[GlobalKey#e1f76 ReorderableListView overlay key] ←
I/flutter ( 9049):     ReorderableListView ← NestedGroup ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ←
I/flutter ( 9049):     IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#25797] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 9049):   parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter ( 9049):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 9049):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 9049):   alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart
I/flutter ( 9049):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter ( 9049):   fit: expand
I/flutter ( 9049):   overflow: clip
I/flutter ( 9049): This RenderObject had the following child:
I/flutter ( 9049):     child 1: _RenderLayoutBuilder#718b7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#68003 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Sample code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Test(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text('Scrollable Header'), NestedGroup()],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NestedGroup extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
        children: List.generate(
            10,
            (position) => ListTile(
                key: ValueKey(position),
                title: Text("Dragable item $position"))),
        onReorder: (d, dfd) {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

in listview give physics like

```html
physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

it works for me

Comment: thats working for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

Official Flutter's `ReorderableListView` is missing a parameter that regular `ListView` does have and the one you need - `shrinkWrap: true`. It's a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25789).

Without this parameter, you have to limit its height yourself (for example, wrap it in a *Container* with fixed height) or remove parent scrollable (*SingleChildScrollView*).

Or you can use some other reorderable widgets that were made by community - like [this one](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reorderable_list) or [that one](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables).

Comment: I can't remove scrollable container by design. and I can't use fixed height - it is a dynamic list =(

Comment: @Vitaly Then you have to use another similar widget. I left 2 packages in the answer. Personally I used `flutter_reorderable_list` in my project with nested scrollables and it's much better than official widget.

Comment: as far as I remember, I tried them, they have the same problem, but I will try again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get a fixed height of a dynamic list you can put it in a Container with the height of yourList.length*HeightOfEachElement.

for example:

```
    Container(
    /*If you don't the height to be bigger than the height of your screen
    use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.
    You can add a -200 to the end if you don't want it to take up the whole 
    screen*/
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            ),
    /*If each of the elements you are creating are 65 pixels high which sort      
    of fits a card widget or something similar...*/
      height: yourList.length * 65.0,
      child: ListView.builder(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I searched for everything and found that ReorderableListView doesn't work inside Column and/or SingleChildScrollView, but you have the possibility to use Column in the header property of ReorderableListView to assemble your interface.

Answer (score 0):

It works now for me without problem, you can try this example with two ReorderableListView nested into  (works also with ReorderableListView.builder) SingleChildScrollView, plus you can nest inside other widgets as well, as you can see from Text examples.

Had hard time with nesting ReorderableListView into ListView, found out this works and posting it here, since it is related to op issue

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// This is the main application widget.

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(10, (int index) => index);
  final List<int> _items2 = List<int>.generate(15, (int index2) => index2);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final Color oddItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.05);
    final Color evenItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.15);
    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('test 1')),
            ListTile(title: Text('test 2')),
            ReorderableListView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
              children: <Widget>[
                for (index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
                  ListTile(
                    key: Key('$index'),
                    tileColor:
                        _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
                    title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
                  ),
              ],
              onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                setState(() {
                  if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                    newIndex -= 1;
                  }
                  final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
                  _items.insert(newIndex, item);
                });
              },
            ),
            ListTile(title: Text('test 3')),
            ListTile(title: Text('test 4')),
            ReorderableListView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
              children: <Widget>[
                for (index2 = 0; index2 < _items2.length; index2++)
                  ListTile(
                    key: Key('$index2'),
                    tileColor:
                        _items2[index2].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
                    title: Text('Item ${_items2[index2]}'),
                  ),
              ],
              onReorder: (int oldIndex2, int newIndex2) {
                setState(() {
                  if (oldIndex2 < newIndex2) {
                    newIndex2 -= 1;
                  }
                  final int item = _items2.removeAt(oldIndex2);
                  _items2.insert(newIndex2, item);
                });
              },
            ),
            ListTile(title: Text('test 5')),
            ListTile(title: Text('test 6')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ReorderableListView.builder has property know as physics. With which we can avoid scrolling of the list.

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `physics` property of `ReorderableListView.builder` to  `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` like this

```
physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```